# Securing file content in folders under Windows

Tags: windows, filesystems, ntfs, file-permissions

Is there a way to allow a user to create a file in a folder under Windows, but not allow them to edit the contents of the files?

This would be analogous to setuid on FreeBSD systems, where files created in a folder would be given different owner from the user creating the file.

Comment: Do you want to retain the owner, or do you want to prevent edits, or do you want both?

Comment: The goal is to prevent edits.  My thought was that by changing owner, permissions can be applied that would restrict edits; but that is me wearing my unix hat.

Comment: I believe that there's a way to partially achieve this. It would allow users to move or copy files to the folder but wouldn't allow users to create, modify, or delete files in the folder. If that gets you what you need I'll post the procedure in an answer.

Comment: I'm curious to see your proposal.  It might be useful.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Its not possible with Windows XP or earlier.  But it is possible with [Windows Vista or Windows 7](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308419).   They both have an upgraded NTFS file system.

If you have XP, you could do it with a FTP server program, such as Filezilla server, where the user can FTP files but not be allowed replace or edit.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Create automatically implies write\change permission.

Comment: That may very well be true.  A link to a reference of this?

Comment: @djangofan: Well, for one thing, I think you're right in that it changed in Vista; as for the reference, good question, I'll look.  In the meantime, take a look at the Advanced Security Settings -> Permission Entry dialog.  The permission is listed as "Create Files/Write Data".  In the basic permissions dialog it's simply "Modify".